Pyspark mapPartition evaluates the function more times than expected
I'm working with PySpark to process large amounts of data. However, I noticed that the function called by mapPartitions is executed one more time than expected. For instance, in the following code block, the reformat function should be called four times but is called five times: four times when the DataFrame is cached and a fifth time when the show method is invoked.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost").appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
data = [
    ('James','Smith','M',3000),
    ('James','Smith','M',3000),
    ('James','Smith','M',3000),
    ('James','Smith','M',3000),
    ('Anna','Rose','F',4100),
    ('Anna','Rose','F',4100),
    ('Anna','Rose','F',4100),
    ('Anna','Rose','F',4100),
    ('Robert','Williams','M',6200), 
    ('Robert','Williams','M',6200), 
    ('Robert','Williams','M',6200), 
    ('Robert','Williams','M',6200), 
]

columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)
df.show()

#Example 1 mapPartitions()
def reformat(partitionData):
    for row in partitionData:
        yield [row.firstname+","+row.lastname,row.salary*10/100]

df2=df.repartition(4).rdd.mapPartitions(reformat).toDF(["name","bonus"])
df2.cache()
df2.show()

In this case, the time may not be an issue. However, for large datasets, it could become a significant problem. Additionally, if the function involves calls to an external API to fetch data or evaluate some logic, it might lead to overlapping or redundant API requests.
I was testing the example above, with a more simple logic, but I have not identified the problem.

When you call df2.cache(), Spark begins to cache the result of the DataFrame df2, but the action to materialize this cache is still delayed until the action is executed.
The transformation pipeline is executed two times when the df2.cache() call is made and df2.show() is executed.
The correct order of executions is below: Make changes in your code:
df2.count() #Transformations will be materialized
df2.cache()
df2.show() # Now it fetches from the cached data


I tried this, however, I got more evaluations. In that case, nine: four given by
count, four by cache, and one more when show is called

The behavior you're observing with mapPartitions in PySpark is due to caching and action evaluation. When you use transformations like mapPartitions and call an action (e.g., show), Spark will recompute the transformation and may invoke the function more times than expected due to how it manages tasks and optimizations.
try this
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost").appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()
data = [
    ('James','Smith','M',3000),
    ('Anna','Rose','F',4100),
    ('Robert','Williams','M',6200), 
]

columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = columns)

def reformat(partitionData):
    for row in partitionData:
        yield [row.firstname+","+row.lastname, row.salary * 0.1]

df2 = df.repartition(4).rdd.mapPartitions(reformat).toDF(["name", "bonus"])
df2.cache()  # Cache the data
df2.count()  # Force materialization
df2.show()   # Reuse cached data

If the repeated evaluation is not desirable, consider forcing the materialization explicitly by triggering an action like .count() or .collect() before further actions. This ensures the data is fully cached and subsequent actions do not trigger recomputation.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.host", "localhost").appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

data = [
    ('James','Smith','M',3000),
    ('Anna','Rose','F',4100),
    ('Robert','Williams','M',6200), 
]

columns = ["firstname","lastname","gender","salary"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)

def reformat(partitionData):
    for row in partitionData:
        yield [row.firstname + "," + row.lastname, row.salary * 0.1]

df2 = df.repartition(4).rdd.mapPartitions(reformat).toDF(["name", "bonus"])

df2.cache()
df2.count()  # Trigger computation and cache the data

df2.show()


I tried this, but I'm still observing the same behavior: one additional evaluation of the reformat function. Specifically, there are four evaluations when cache is called and one more when count is called.

Added my extended opinion. Be patient.
